'qpdf' is needed for checks on size reduction of PDF's warning
I'm trying to get no warnings or notes on my R package i'm developing. I get the following warning and it has been driving me crazy this last days.
❯ checking for unstated dependencies in examples ... OK
   WARNING
  'qpdf' is needed for checks on size reduction of PDFs

I've installed qpdf with install.packages("qpdf") and then executed library(qpdf) but it does not disappear when calling check() on the package. I don't know what else to do...

Is this on Windows? You might need to install qpdf.exe system-wide.

Where can i find that qpdf.exe? Is there going to be any problem when I submit this to CRAN?

I don't use Windows so I can't guide you through the process of installing software. Also this might or might not work to deal with the warning, if it changes anything with CRAN I don't know.

I just appears when calling check() i did not add it "manually" that's why i don't understand why it's happening... The PDF is not huge...
In some functions i use plot which will generate intermediate pdf's when generating the .html of the .Rmd file that contains the Vignette i've done. Could it be that?
